# How to fix 'error: no suitable video mode found' while booting Kali Linux with integrated graphics and NVIDIA GPU?

Tags: kali-linux, nvidia

I am trying install kali linux but I am running into the same error while booting "error: no suitable video mode found. Booting in blind mode" after which nothing happends and I am forced to reboot. I have read through every thread I could find on the topic and tried the suggested changes to grub but I cant get it to work. I have a intel i7 with integrated graphics and an external NVIDIA GPU. i use a 8gb usb hard disk with the last version of kali 2023.2 downloaded from the kali.org

have someone a solution ?

Comment: seeing that Kali is definitely not the operating system you want to play games on or watch videos, disable the Nvidia GPU in the UEFI setup, if possible? Why exactly are you using Kali?

Comment: Every other day a new person shows up trying to set up Kali. Is there something I don't know or don't understand? Why does this obscure Linux distro for penetration testing see so much activity? The solution is not to use Linux. You wanna learn cyber security? Install VM e.g. VirtualBox and have fun.

Comment: i want to connect with the integrated wifi adaptater of the lab . with VMware or virtual box i need an external one , so i bought and the driver won't .

Answer (score 0):

I used to get in trouble with this boot error.
I fixed it using the "live cd" iso instead of "installer" iso. Then I was able to install Kali.

Answer (score 0):

They fixed the bug. Redownload the installer from kali.org

Comment: Welcome to the site, and thank you for your contribution. You may want to add a link to the release notes in which the bug fix is mentioned.